# MVC 4 HiddenFor field not appearing in rendered markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hidden-field

Am using MVC 4 and want to maintain some values on postback, so they're going into hidden fields.  In essence:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EventId);
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.paymentMethodId);
}
```

But the hidden fields are not appearing in the rendered markup and are therefore - obviously - missing on postback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `@`, `@Html.HiddenFor()`. Otherwise you're just executing the helper method, but not actually doing anything with the output.

Answer (score 2):

As dombenoit says, missing the "@" directive, and also need to remove the ";" from the end of each line for some reason, so the corrected code sample looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EventId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.paymentMethodId)
}
```

Now renders the hidden fields as expected.

Comment: So Dom had the correct answer, and thus should have received the credit?